# Force GORM to use specific INTEGER type when auto-migrating to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, go, psql, go-gorm

My model in Go is:

```
type Sales_Daily_db struct {
    Nation_shipping string
    Date             datatypes.Date
    Impressions      int `gorm:"type:integer;"`
    Clicks           int `gorm:"type:integer;"`
    Cost             float32
    ATB              float32
    OKL              float32
}
```

When running `AutoMigrate()` using the above model, I want the `impressions` and `clicks` columns in pSQL database to be of type `integer`. However, even with those `gorm` tags, they still ended up as type `int4`. I have tried `int2 int4 int8` manually with the tags above, and they all worked accordingly. Additionally, when I try `int` tag, they are forced into `int8`. How to fix this behavior and get `integer` type specifially in pSQL?

Edit: I am using DBeaver to look at the database.

Comment: `integer` is [an alias](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-INT) for `int4` in Postgres - both are exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to PostgreSQL documentation, this is stated:

```
SQL only specifies the integer types integer (or int), smallint, and bigint.  
The type names int2, int4, and int8 are extensions, which are also used by some other SQL database systems.
```

You should be fine with `int`, `integer`, `smallint` and `bigint`. Anything beyond that is just aliases.